# Ajax based search - how to put results into datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am trying to make ajax based search but i am very new in javascript and ajax. I need sorting, filtering etc. for results so i put results into Datatables.
First of all i'am using standard html form input (it is main search field):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formmethod="post" oninput="return delayExecute();" id="name" name="name" size="61" autofocus/>
```

It calls delayExecute() function when user put something into form. Next, one second after user is finished writing the script run ajax request. Script looks like that:

```
<script>     
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 700;

function delayExecute()
{
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(
        function(){makeAjaxRequest(name)},
        1000
        );
    return true;
}

function makeAjaxRequest(name) {
    $('#loading')
        .show()
var myrequest = $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_search',
    type: 'post',
    data: {name: $('input#name').val()},
    ajaxSend: function() {


    },
    success: function(response) {

        $('table#dataTables-example tbody').html(response);

    },
    complete:function(){
        //
        $('#loading')
        .hide();   
         $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
                // "destroy": true,
                "processing": true,
                 "aaSorting": [],
                 "iDisplayLength": 10,
                 "aLengthMenu":[[10, 15, 25, 35, 50, 100, -1], [10, 15, 25, 35, 50, 100, "All"]]
             }).columnFilter(
             {
                 aoColumns: [
                                 {type: "null"},
                                 {sSelector: "#mag_filter_column", type: "select"},

                             ]
             }
             );
    }
});
```

};

In Php file (ajax_request) i read data from data base. Next I use echo function to put things into table like that:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$some_variable.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$other_variable.'</td>';
echo '</tr>;
```

And table in the view looks like that:

```
<table class="main-search table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Col</th>
            <th>War</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Quantity</th>
             <th>Descripion</th>
             <th>Photo</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

This whole thing almost work. When i make search for the first time it loads everything into datatable and everything works good (pagination, sorting etc). But when i do second search (change some word for example) - ajax serch runs, it find something but the data doesn't load into datatable. I think that i need to find way to refresh datatable plugin. I tried to use datatable.clear(), datatable.destroy() and couple other things but nothing works well for me. What is the right way to do it?

My datatable plugin version: DataTables 1.10.5

jquery version: 2.1.1

Comment: There is a 'reload` method for dataTables: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() . What happens when you use `destroy()` ? Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: To use destroy i assigned variable mytable to datatable initialisation like that: var mytable = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({....and so on. It now shows error: mytable is undefined

Comment: Did you use something like this: 
`var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
 

    table.destroy();
` you could add the in the `oninput` event

Comment: Your last answer helped a lot. I put your code into my function delayExecute() and now the datatable load every time i search something. But there is still one small issue. Now every time when i put some character into form it runs destroy(). This cause a performance issue. Its kind of laggy when i write something.//edit: I put destroy() code into ajax success event just before html(response) and now it works great!

Comment: Right, yeah, in oninput will be problematic. Can you do it onblur or have it on a button (probably better anyway)